SSIS Convert time to seconds
I receive an excel file with time fields in the format  :00:00, but there are times when the hour will be populated
| Time | Seconds
| --------
| 1:03:48 |
| :52:10  |
I'm having a bit of trouble converting to seconds. I've tried using TOKEN function, but not recognizing the hour segment
The results should be



Time
Seconds




1:03:48
3828


:52:10
3130




The easiest way to work with strings in SSIS is via a Script Component.

Add a script component transformation
For input columns, select the column with the time string.  In my example I used time

For inputs and outputs, add a column, Seconds and set the datatype to double:

On the script tab, hit the edit script button and modify the method, Input0_ProcessInputRow():


   public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        string current_time = Row.time.Trim();
        try
        {
            if (current_time.StartsWith(":"))
            {
                current_time = "0" + current_time;
            }
            Row.Seconds = TimeSpan.Parse(current_time).TotalSeconds;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ComponentMetaData.FireError(10, "Convert to Seconds", e.Message, "", 0, out bool cancel);
        }
    }


Output will look like this:


Thank You. I have over 50+ columns to convert to seconds, hat's why i was looking at derive column in SSSIS

A derived column is not going to save you any trouble.  You would still need to configure an expression for each column.  If this is not an acceptable answer, please update the question to better articulate the problem.

Yes, I am aware an expression is required for each column, i just trying to have a working expression which can be applied to all.
